# iSCSI connection drops frequently - Synology NAS

Tags: windows, networking, iscsi, network-attached-storage, synology

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Server connected through iSCSI to my Synology Rackstation 2414+. The problem is that the connection drops very very frequently, up to 10 times a day (manually restored connections). The event IDs in Windows appear in the following order:

```
Event ID 20 - Connection to the target was lost. The initiator will attempt to retry the connection.
Event ID 7 - The initiator could not send an iSCSI PDU. Error status is given in the dump data.
Event ID 7 - The initiator could not send an iSCSI PDU. Error status is given in the dump data.
Event ID 7 - The initiator could not send an iSCSI PDU. Error status is given in the dump data.
Event ID 10 - Login request failed. The login response packet is given in the dump data.
```

Synology is and iSCSI dedicated NIC are connected to a dedicated switch, on a separate subnet.
What might be the problem? Or what other information do you need to get a better picture of the situation? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

So, I have been running wireshark on the server's iSCSI dedicated NIC, and as it appears, the server send a reset (RST) packet to the NAS after not receiving ACK packets for some time. The last packets sent from the server to the NAS before (as detected from wireshark) are all retransmitted ones sending a SCSI Inquirycommand ... those packets, besides being retransmitted, don't get aknowledged. Now I am running tcpdump on my Synology to see if the ACK packets are sent but not delivered or if there is something else going on ...

Comment: Is this a clue `Login request failed`? Have you tried disabling authentication to see if it has any affect on the problem? What does the dump data say?

Comment: Authentication is already disabled :( ... Dump data does not say anything sadly,from the  binary data of the login response packet I can see only the target IQN. Nothing more...